# Improve TFS2013 Pull Request merge success rate

Tags: tfs

In TFS2013.4 (version 12.0.31101.0), we are using Git and a pull request based workflow. I am looking for a way to improve the pull request merging ability of TFS.

We branch from master, make our changes, then push this new branch to the TFS server and create a pull review. TFS reports that a merge can be completed successfully.

[image: Merge succeeded]

When an unrelated change is then made to master between branch creation and pull request merge. TFS invariably claims that it cannot make the merge itself, and it must be merged manually.

[image: Merge failed. This merge cannot be completed on the server. You will need to merge locally then push to the server.]

"Why?" text: `Merge failed. This merge cannot be completed on the server. You will need to merge locally then push to the server.`

In the two screenshots above, I have done just that - branch from master, commit, push, create pull request, merge is possible. Checkout master, make change, push, merge is not possible. But using "git merge" from the command line works flawlessly without user intervention.

How can I reduce the failure rate of merging pull requests in TFS, such that we only need manual intervention when there is a legitimate conflict - not just when master has moved on?

Answer (score 1):

This workflow has been significantly improved in TFS 2015. Some of those improvements will be in 2013.5 but most are 2015.

You would be fully supported to use TFS 2015 in production and i have already been sucessfull with customers.

I don't think that you can solve this yourself and the TFS Product Team are likely continuously looking to improve this workflow. It is however new and they are iteratively making it better.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the suggestion. I'll have another look at 2015 when I'm back at work and see if that solves my issues.

Comment: I've just had another look at TFS 2015, and the same issue persists.

Branch from master
Commit to new branch
Push new branch and open pull request
Pull request says it can merge fine
If there is any change to master (Eg, new commit) before the pull request is merged, then it cannot merge fine, even if the changes are completely unrelated and coudln't possibly conflict.

Comment: @SirSquidness stumbled across this question, just commenting to say that we have been using TF 2015 RTM with the workflow you described, without the failed merge problem. For us it just asks us to reevaluate the merge if there is a new commit on master.

Comment: I guess I'll give TFS 2015 another look; do you know if you've done anything special to your TFS installation? And you definitely don't need to update the pull request source before the pull request will complete?

Comment: @SirSquidness did tfs 2015 fix the issue for you?

Comment: @VadimKirilchuk I haven't updated our production server to 2015 yet, but the test environment I set up did not fix the issue. However, TFS 2015 Update 1 RC has been released and I have not yet tested with this.